# Unable to pass a variable parameter to jasper report

Tags: grails, groovy, jasper-reports, gsp, jasper-plugin

So, I have created a simple CRUD app using groovy on grails and I want to use jasper reporting plugin to get some simple reports on the database. I have set up a simple G:select to pick from a drop down list, and hitting the PDF icon I am bringing back a blank page. gsp is below

```
<div id="page-body" role="main">
<p>Please select one of the following options</p>
<div>
<g:select optionKey="id" 
optionValue="artist" 
name="artist" 
id="MusicCatalogue" 
value="${artist}" 
from="${multicatalogue.MusicCatalogue.list()}">
</g:select>
</div>
<div> <g:jasperReport jasper="report1" format="PDF" name="Music Catalogue" />
<input type="hidden" name="artist" value="${artist}" />
</div>
</div>
```

and then the jrxml looks like the below

```
<parameter name="artist" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["<parameter error>"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT   *
    FROM
    MusicCatalogue where ARTIST = $P{artist}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ALBUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ARTIST" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TRACK" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="ARTIST">
```

ideas????

Answer (score 0):

Try replace

```
<g:jasperReport jasper="report1" format="PDF" name="Music Catalogue" />
<input type="hidden" name="artist" value="${artist}" />
```

With

```
<g:jasperReport jasper="report1" format="PDF" name="Music Catalogue">
<input type="hidden" name="artist" value="${artist}" />
</g:jasperReport>
```

Also, make sure that `${artist}` returns a string value, else the report will use the defaultValue of `artist` parameter that might ruin your query.

Comment: I am afraid that has not worked, what did you mean by "Also, make sure that ${artist} returns a string value" the select has a range of strings but I am not sure how to pass them to the jasper report.

Comment: Your problem is you're getting a blank page right. Im saying maybe the value of your hidden textfield which is `${artist}` is not your desired value thats why your getting a blank page (because you use it inside the query of your report). Because in terms of passing parameter to jasperreport, I think your code is valid.

Comment: at which point is my g:select actually the problem in that it is not passing the required parameter? I think my issue is that I am unable to actually pass anything. the select appears as a drop down message BUT crucially even is I create a submit button no value is actually captured.